# contour detection and manipulating the contour

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

[Original Image before finding contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CeHK.jpg)Finding the diameter of the inner circle after the contour detection

I have an image, and I am using openCv and python to detect the contour as shown in the attached image.

The object under examination is an irregular shaped object(Image attached), need to find the diameter of that detected object.

I am using findcontours and filtering out the contours based on their areas[Description of the image :green lines-contours detected, black line looking to find the inner circle like the one marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxDRk.png)

Is there a way to get the circle as shown using openCV-python

Can anyone let know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Can you please provide few more details like what you have actually tried? And the original image that you worked on to get the results. Thank you

Comment: I added the original image